# Invoke-sqlcmd output without "quotes" and headers

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

**Output example:**

```
#TYPE System.Data.DataRow <---
"PersonalNr" <---
"00001005"
"00001008"
"00001009"
"00001013"
"00001019"
"00001024"
```

**Requirements:**

I want a output without the 2 first lines and without the quote symbols, how can i do that?

For the headers I tried the options `-h -1` but the output is still the same. Is it even possible with `Sqlcmd`?

**Current Code:**

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance SERVER -h -1 -Query $QueryFmt | Export-CSV $AttachmentPath
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that `Invoke-Sqlcmd` =/= sqlcmd.exe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code should work:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "" -Database "" -Query "" | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter "," | Select-Object -Skip 1 | % {$_ -replace '"', ""} | Out-File ("C:\test.csv") -Force -Encoding ascii
```

`Invoke-Sqlcmd` produces:

```
PersonalNr       
---    
00001005  
00001001  
00001006  
00001007  
00001008
```

With `Export-Csv`, the file looks like:

```
#TYPE System.Data.DataRow
"PersonalNr"
"00001005"
"00001001"
"00001006"
"00001007"
"00001008"
```

Using my above mentioned code, I get the file looking like this:

```
00001005
00001001
00001006
00001007
00001008
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Output is still the same for me, are you sure it should work with the csv export at the end?

Comment: Output: 

    #TYPE System.String
    "Length"
    "19"
    "19"
    "19"
.........

Comment: Yes, sorry. I realized just after I pressed answer that it would not work. Did you try my updated answer?

Comment: I would use a trim before a replace. That way if there are any embedded quotes you will not have to worry about removing them. Also would `Select-Object -Skip 2` also remove the first row of actual data?

Comment: Yes, but the first row of data was to be excluded here. I've added trim in the replace, thanks

Comment: Where did you get the idea the first row of _data_ was to be excluded? I meant I would used `trim('"')` instead of `-replace`

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

**$query_result | Format-Table -AutoSize -Wrap -HideTableHeaders**

Comment: This is the BEST answer,  SHORTEST yet effective,  should have more likes !

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
## You data for export to csv
$csv = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance SERVER  -Query $QueryFmt
# 

##Will remove type information  and will remove header
$csv | Export-CSV -NoTypeInformation | select -Skip 1 | Set-Content $AttachmentPath 
#
```

Comment: `-h -1` is for sqlcmd.exe. That does not have a mapping to `Invoke-SQLcmd` as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/invoke-sqlcmd-cmdlet. Even if it did work you would be removing data with `select -Skip 1`